# Daisy chaining conditions in Rails controller action.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The index method of my controller looks as follows:

```
  def index
    if params["feed_source_id"]
      @feeds = Feed.find_all_by_feed_source_id(params["feed_source_id"])
    else
      @feeds = Feed.all
  end
```

I just added the Metasearch Gem to my app, and it defines the search in my index as:

```
@search = Feed.search(params[:search])
```

How can I daisy chain both of these conditions so that @search will perform the search as well as include the find_all_by_feed_source_id condition?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're aiming at - besides doing both searches in the index action? Do you want a union or intersection of both search results?

If you want a union, you *could* do something like
@feeds = @feeds | @search.all 
in addition to all the code above, which would give you a terrible performance.

I had a brief look at the Metasearch Gem, and it should give you the possibility to include the feed_source_id as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You want the AND of these conditions, right?

I think this should work:

```
Feed.search({ :feed_source_id_eq => params[:feed_source_id] }.merge(params[:search]))
```

Comment: I get an undefined method `merge' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Feed:0x00000101b7cbe8>

Comment: Weird. Make sure you're invoking `merge` on the hash (argument to the `search` method), not on what `search` returns.

Comment: The whole reason I'm trying to do this is to get my column sorted by asc and desc in the view. Any recommendations as to how to easily accomplish this?

Comment: I think `meta_search` comes with a helper method `sort_link` to do that, have you tried it? Ex. in your controller action: `@search = Feed.search(...)` and then in the view `<%= sort_link @search, :column %>`